# List all files permissions recursively *nix/Windows/Solaris

Tags: permissions, reporting

I know this is technically a 3 part question, but it is all in the same vein.  I need a way to generate a report, most likely text based, that will display all of the file permissions on all directories and files within a tree.  The tree has a depth of X, I say X because it is possible that this tree will grow.  Regardless I have a start for a *nix implementation, but it is definitely lacking.

*nix

> ll */ */ */ * > perms.txt

This is of course pretty terrible based on the number of times I would need to repeat this, it does however generate the results that I desire.  I imagine Solaris will look much the same, Windows I am not sure what to expect.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows, there's CACLS, but it doesn't recurse automatically to list ACLs. Here's a VBScript that will do that part for you: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vbscript/VBScript_ACL_Crawl.aspx

On Linux it's probably simplest (and most portable) to use `ls -lR` as [ire_and_curses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410249/list-all-files-permissions-recursively-nix-windows-solaris/3410271#3410271) says.

Answer (score 8):

Is recursive `ls` sufficient?

```
ls -lR
```

Another good option is [tree](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree), which has nice output.

```
tree -p
```

Comment: Thank you that is quite sufficient on *nix and most likely Solaris.  Any suggestion for Windows?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything useful about Windows.

Comment: You only know useless things about Windows? :-)

Comment: You will want to use `ls -lAR` rather than `ls -lR` so that filenames starting with a dot are not hidden (. and .. stay hidden).

Comment: @Vinko Vrsalovic - Or perhaps that I don't know anything that Windows is useful for? ;) Truth be told, I know almost nothing about Windows, useful or otherwise...

Answer (score 3):

On Windows use [SetACL](http://helgeklein.com/setacl/) to get a full listing like this:

```
SetACL.exe -on "path" -ot file -actn list -lst "f:tab;w:d,o" -rec cont_obj
```

That creates a permission listing in tabular (= human readable) format including owner and DACL, recursing over all sub-containers and sub-objects.

Comment: Straight from the author!  You've created a very helpful tool.  Thank you!